# Why do these dark lines appear in render mode?

Tags: rendering

Black lines appear on my mesh when moved away from the origin. The black lines intensify as the mesh is moved further and further from the origin. The black lines only appear in the render view. Any help on the issue will be greatly appreciated. Attached is a photo of the issue and the blend file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://developer.blender.org/T43835) and limitation of Cycles. Does happen in render also, not only in render view.

The solution is to keep everything close by scene origin. You can have the camera stationary close to origin and then move the scene if it is big inversely to do "camera motion".